# Two-Person Game With An Unfair Coin: Probability of Winning

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Naoki and I are playing a game with an unfair coin that is rigged to come up heads with probability $\frac35$ and tails with probability $\frac25$. Naoki goes first, we take turns, and the first player to flip a tail wins. What is Naoki's probability of winning?

---

Let $P_n$ equal the probability that Naoki will win, and $P_m$ that I will win.
$$P_n=\frac{2}{5}+\frac{3}{5}P_m$$
$$P_m=\frac{2}{5}P_n~~~~~$$
Then I solved the system of equations to get that $P_n=\frac{10}{19}$ but that's incorrect.  A correct solution and pointing out where I miscalculated is appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: It isn't clear what $P_m$ means.  Do you just mean $P_m=1-P_n$ or do you mean "the probability that 'I' win conditioned on Naoki missing the first turn"?

Comment: The simplest way to avoid such confusion is to do a two-step recursion.  Thus $P_n=\frac 25\times 1+\frac 35\times \frac 25\times 0 + \frac 35\times \frac 35\times P_n$.

Comment: You should have $P_m=\frac35P_n$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Naoki wins the game if: she wins the first turn or, if not, then you loose the first turn and then she wins the game from there.

You win the game if: Naoki looses the turn and then either you win the turn or you loose the turn but win the game from there.

That is: partition on the first turn noting that the game repeats if nobody wins on the first turn.

$$P_n = \tfrac 2 5 + \tfrac 35\cdot\tfrac 35\cdot P_n$$

$$P_m = \tfrac 35\cdot(\tfrac 25+\tfrac 35P_m)$$

Comment: So $P_n=\frac{5}{8}$ and $P_m=\frac{3}{8}?$

Answer (score 1):

In any round of two,
either Naoki wins on first turn, or doesn't and puts you in the same position as she was at start.

Thus odds in favor of Naoki $= 1:\frac35 = 5:3\;$, and $\;P_n = \frac58$